# Prevent Launcher/Main activity being launched by another Application

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

As title, I have an application that only want user to launch from home screen or the history menu. Can we detect whether the app is launched by any other application?

I have tried the intent.getFlags() method but unfortunately seems the caller application can set the flag value to the desired value too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect, but what you can do is set special permissions in the manifest using `<permission />` tag and set `android:permission` attribute in the desired activity. That way, it will be available only for applications having you signature. Here are [security tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html) in detail.

Comment: What about allowing specific applications to call my application but not using the same signature? Is it possible?

Comment: Seems using special permissions in Launcher activity will cause the app unable to launch from home screen...